# Arangodb, simply get back the id after running an insert query in php?

Tags: php, database, arangodb

```
$query = new ArangoStatement($db,[
        'query' => 'INSERT @tweet IN tweets RETURN NEW',
        'bindVars' =>[
            'tweet' => $tweet
        ]
    ]);
    $res = $query->execute();
    // get the id back somehow?
```

Not finding any solutions for this simple task online and I see no way to retrieve it after running $query->getAll since it's protected

Answer (score 0):

You can directly return `_id` from your query, execute the query, get all cursor data and pop the only value that should be in the array:

```php
$query = new ArangoStatement($db,[
  'query' => 'INSERT @tweet IN tweets RETURN NEW._id',
  'bindVars' =>[
    'tweet' => $tweet
  ]
]);
$cursor = $query->execute();
$id = array_pop($cursor->getAll())
// print_r($id);
```